# append to the container div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Incassi previsionali</legend>
    <div class="sez-form">
        <table id="inc_prev">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Mese: </label>
                <select name="mese[]" id="mese[]">
                    <option value="1">Gennaio</option>
                    <option value="2">Febbraio</option>
                    <option value="3">Marzo</option>
                    <option value="4">Aprile</option>
                    <option value="5">Maggio</option>
                    <option value="6">Giugno</option>
                    <option value="7">Luglio</option>
                    <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                    <option value="9">Settembre</option>
                    <option value="10">Ottobre</option>
                    <option value="11">Novembre</option>
                    <option value="12">Dicembre</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Anno: </label>
                <select name="anno[]" id="anno[]">
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")-1; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")-1; ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y"); ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+1; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")+1; ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+2; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")+2; ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+3; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")+3; ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+4; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")+4; ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+5; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")+5; ?></option>
                    <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+6; ?>"><?php echo date("Y")+6; ?></option>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td><label>Percentuale: </label><input value="" size="15" maxlength="14" class="importo" name="percent[]" type="text"/>%</td>
            <td><img class="addRow" src="../images/plus.png"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I focus the .importo input and then focus it out I want to append something to the container div (at bottom).
So I tried:

```
$(document).on('blur','.importo',function(){
    $(this).parents().eq(2).append('<p>Qui le singole previsioni</p>');
});
```

but this will add the text to all the parent elements up to the third level.
How to add it only at the bottom of the div?
Also, should I use .one to fire this only once? I am actually using on since user can add as many of these fieldset as necessary and for each fieldset I want to fire it only once

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5gdy0qz/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `parents()`:

```
$(document).on('blur','.importo',function(){
    $(this).closest("div.sez-form").append('<p>Qui le singole previsioni</p>');
});
```

Comment: looks like a joke but with this code I get the text appendend one time right after the input and three times at div bottom

Comment: @LelioFaieta Do one thing, then change `.append()` to `.html()` for a new `div` at the end. `:)` Problem solved.

Comment: Fixed... changed to html and back to append and now it is working... :)

Comment: It is always better you add a status div or something that helps to store messages. `:)` Agree?

Comment: And you can always call `$(".status").html(error_message)` or something.

Comment: real code is to retrieve some data from db, based on what is in the input and do some math on them... the text was just to keep the question simple :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `closest()` to target the specific `div` you want to append to. Try this:

```
$(document).on('blur','.importo',function(){
    $(this).closest('.sez-form').append('<p>Qui le singole previsioni</p>');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/dp04ow7h/)